# How to convert list of orders into a date-based calendar

Tags: openoffice

First, I'm aware this is a fairly complex question, if you have a better place for me to ask it, I would be happy to ask again somewhere else.

Here is the question: I've got an open-office document in which I have two sheets:

- The first sheet is my production planning and contains columns with the week number as headers and lines are produced units;
- The second sheet contains lines with the next orders. Columns are ordering date, and then the repartition of the order depending the products.

I would like to get the orders from the order-sheet appear in the planning-sheet. Problem being that the week-number doesn't appear in the order-sheet, making it hard to accomplish.

Here are a few captures:

[image: Production planning]
[image: Orders]

I've tried (and succeeded) to create an intermediate matrix in which I have the weeknumber as headers and then for each order a line. I managed to get the line number of the order appear and otherwise display "false", but now I don't know where to go with this.

Do you have any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for my problem. I can use the `SOMME.SI` function which solves my problem, like this:

`=SOMME.SI(Commandes.$C$4:$C$1000;"="&AC$4;Commandes.$H$4:$H$1000)`

Where `A4` is the number of the week. As simple as this !